# Alternative to quantmod for bid/ask info

Tags: r, quantmod, stockquotes

Previously I used this to get closing bid/ask prices:

```
library("quantmod")
getQuote(Symbols = symbols, 
           src = "yahoo",
           what=yahooQF(c("Bid","Ask", "Volume")))
```

Now I get the error:

```
Error in .yahooSession(TRUE) : unable to get yahoo crumb
```

```
> packageVersion('quantmod')
[1] ‘0.4.24’
```

Reading [this](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/382) it appears that Yahoo! is no longer an option with `quantmod`.

src = "av" doesn't return bid/ask info.
Neither does [Tiingo](https://www.tiingo.com/)

Is there a free solution for R users for less than ten quotes per day for bid/ask info?

Comment: looks like there is this: https://data.nasdaq.com/tools/r

Comment: also check this: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/393

Comment: As @Mark suggested "Yahoo unhappy about crumbs #393" got it working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quantmod` is working again after running:

```
remotes::install_github("ethanbsmith/quantmod@fix_404_handle_getquote_gdpr_errors")
```

Source: [ethanbsmith, Github](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/393#issuecomment-1649899398)

Comment: This has been merged to quantmod/main. No need to install from the fork.